# Using python, how do I convert dates that are stored as m(m)/dd/yyyy in a csv file to yyyy-mm-dd for use in sqlite?

Tags: python, date, csv, sqlite

I am working with a csv file that I contains a date field, but the dates are formatted like 1/8/1986 when I need them to be read into a sqlite3 database in this format 1986-8-1 or 1986-08-01.  I have seen a lot of people talking about this issue, but I haven't really understood the answers being given.  Here is how I think it would work though:  for a specific field, the csv reader outputs to a converter method that reparses the date in a format that can be used by sqlite.  I don't think that sqlite itself can be used to make the conversion code, otherwise I would probably use that instead.  I am not sure how this converter method would work with loadcsv method though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to install additional packages you can do following:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> d = '1/8/1986'
>>> date(*reversed([int(x) for x in d.split('/')])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'1986-08-01'
```

Comment: Where would this go in relation to the code to read from the csv file?

Comment: @cluemein: Once you've read a row from CSV file you need to convert every column that contains a date before writing to DB. I really can't give more detailed answer without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Actually figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install python-dateutil`

then

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parse
fixed_date_string = date_parse(my_date_string).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

or just do this ... its probably easier for you

```
import re
with open("fixed_csv.csv","wb") as f:
     f.write(re.sub("(\d\d?)/(\d\d)/(\d{4})","\\3-\\2-\\1",open("my.csv").read())
```

then just use "fixed_csv.csv" as your input ...

Comment: Where would this go in relation to the code to read from the csv file?

Comment: I am sorry but you may be in over your head... if this is a class assignment you should probably ask your teacher for some help ... and do some more tutorials ... you do this anywhere you want to "fix the date"

Comment: Where to put it I mean.  Its not a school project, just something I'm doing at home.  Just never had to use python this way before.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple with no imports:

```
olddate="1/21/2010"
m,d,y=map(str,olddate.split('/'))
newdate=y+'-'+m+'-'+d
```

Comment: Where would this go in relation to the code to read from the csv file?